# R How do I convert a column of date in "yy-mmm" character into a new column of "yyyy" in integer to do graph visualization?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do an analysis of the property prices over time for the different market segments.

I want to do an analysis of the year (x-axis) by comparing on a year on year basis. (like 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020) - in integer format

However the column of data I would like to use as x-axis arrange the dates as such ("19-Jan", "19-Feb", "19-Mar", "19-Apr"..."19-Dec") in a "yy-mmm" character format.

I wanted it the whole column of data to be converted from characters to number/integer as such "2019" as an example.

I would like to analyze the property prices over different market segments on a year on year basis rather than on a monthly basis like from 18-Jan to 18-Feb...to 19-Jan.

How can I convert the column containing character values of "19-Jan" to "2019" (Perhaps to create another column to contain the converted values in the same dataframe)

This conversion is important for me to plot a line graph consisting of the 3 different segment as 3 legends.

I have left an example of the ggplot line graph code from the start as a guide to what I am trying to do:

Btw I have 3 factors in the market segment column of my data.

```
`#Load dplyr
library(dplyr)`
`#Filter 3 sets of data -  #1 - RCR
rcr_data<-filter(URA_data,URA_data$Market.Segment %in% "RCR")
rcr_data`
#Filter 3 sets of data - #2 - OCR
ocr_data<-filter(URA_data,URA_data$Market.Segment %in% "OCR")
ocr_data

#Filter 3 sets of data - #3 - CCR
ccr_data<-filter(URA_data,URA_data$Market.Segment %in% "CCR")
ccr_data

#Create Variable X - RCR Year (Exclusive)
rcr_year<-rcr_data$Date.of.Sale

#Create Variable X - OCR Year (Exclusive)
ocr_year<-ocr_data$Date.of.Sale

#Create Variable x - CCR Year (Exclusive)
ccr_year<-ccr_data$Date.of.Sale

#create Variable Y - RCR (Exclusive)
rcr_price<-rcr_data$Price....

#create variable Y - OCR (Exclusive)
ocr_price<-ocr_data$Price....

#create variable Y - CCR (Exclusive)
ccr_price<-ccr_data$Price....

#Load Library
library(ggplot2)

#Avoid Scientific Notation
options(scipen=999)

# Line Graph Visualization
ggplot()+
  geom_line(rcr_data,mapping=aes(x=rcr_year,y=rcr_price, color="RCR"))+
  geom_line(ocr_data,mapping=aes(x=ocr_year,y=ocr_price,color="OCR"))+
  geom_line(ccr_data,mapping=aes(x=ccr_year,y=ccr_price,color="CCR"))+
  scale_color_manual("",
                     breaks = c("RCR","OCR","CCR"),
                     values = c("RCR"="green","OCR"="red","CCR"="blue"))+
  ggtitle("Chua Shao Yang - Property Price by Different Market Segments")+xlab("Year")+ylab("Property Prices")+
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(color="red",size=12, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="red",size=12, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(color="red",size=12, face="bold")
  )
```

This is my failed line graph
[image]

I have tried to attach a screenshot of my raw data.

[image]

In need of assistance so thanks for looking through. Need further clarification can ask

My Raw excel data file link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cynVkZv0aJRjwFgvVzlSRG7G-6t96cAgXOZMTJdPkC8/edit#gid=80649901

I link it to my google drive. The prupose of this data is to help me do graph visualizations on my own (reference I have in image):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xllsU.png)

**Updated** How do I add markers to the existing graph lines? My Sample Code

```
Plotly<-URA_data %>%
  mutate(year = 2000 + as.integer(substring(Date.of.Sale, 1, 2))) %>%
  group_by(year, Type.of.Sale) %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(Price....))%>%
  ggplot(aes(year, Price, color = Type.of.Sale)) + geom_line()+
  labs(color="Type of Sales")+
  ggtitle("Sales Type")+
  xlab("Year")+ylab("Price")+
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(color="red",size=14,face="bold.italic",hjust=0.5),
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="blue",size=14,face="bold"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(color="green",size=14,face="bold")
  )


library(plotly)

Graph<-ggplotly(Plotly)
Graph
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1Li.jpg)

Comment: You should not add data as images. We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a year column, take average of `Price` for each year and `Market.Segment` and plot the line graph.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

URA_data <- read.csv('URAdata - URAdata.csv')

URA_data %>%
  mutate(year = 2000 + as.integer(substring(Date.of.Sale, 1, 2))) %>%
  group_by(year, Market.Segment) %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, Price, color = Market.Segment)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to get an additional column for the year but the graph generates vertical lines for the market segment which is not useful in helping me to observe the market segment prices changes over the year.

Comment: Do you have data for more than 1 year? Can you provide your data using `dput` so that I can test this?

Comment: Do I put the data in the comment section or should I edit my question?

Comment: You can edit your post to include the data.

Comment: I have updated my post. There should be a google drive link to the excel (google sheet) and a reference image to the outcome that I wanted

Comment: The file gives access denied error. It would be better if you provide your data using `dput` so that we don't have to go to some other place to get data.

Comment: I have updated this properly in dput() format. I only have 66 rows because the data is extensive.

Comment: That is not `dput` output. How do we copy data from it and use it in R? Did you read the link which I shared with you above. This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 . You can add first 20 rows of your data. Type `dput(head(URA_data, 20))` in the console and copy the output in your post.

Comment: I have put in the dput output

Comment: I just realised that the dput output only has for year 2019 Jan. I have made the google drive link available to everybody who has the link. That is more extensive and you should be able to have access to it with more years of data from 2016 to 2019.

Comment: See my updated answer to plot the data and also to extract the year.

Comment: Great! The graph comes out useful. I experimented with it by using the median with the mean. The trajectory of the graph seems different, which is more accurate?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to look at. But I think `mean` value would be more useful in general.

Comment: Can I also come back here for some advice as I continue to experiment with different categorical variables?

Comment: How is mean and median different? Because mean takes in outliers, wouldn't that skew the data?

Comment: If you have some specific programming question you can ask that as a new question.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have updated the graph but I am having issues adding markers to my lines, can you provide some advice?

Comment: Please don't extend the question in the same post. Every post should solve only one specific problem. Ask that as a new question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for indicating

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (assuming all your dates start in the new millenium):

```
x <- c("19-Feb", "20-Jan")

as.numeric(paste0("20", str_remove(x, "-(.*)")))
```

gives:

```
#[1] 2019 2020
```